# Can we install Codeigniter in Magento?

Tags: codeigniter, magento

I tried a lot with installing codeigniter in Magento, and I am doubtful now whether it is possible or not. In a critical situation. Is it possible to install codeigniter in Magento ? And can we access codeigniter files through magento? Any links or tutorials for supporting ?

Comment: What do you mean with "in Magento"? Of course you can install both next to each other in the same environment and access all the files. But what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I login in Magento's session using that is it possible to authenticate in CodeIgniter's session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the framework are in PHP itself, the answer is yes. You can install codeigniter by creating a folder with **CI** files on it. It works. You can share session variables to control the session in between two systems.

But the question is why exactly do you want to do like so ? If you are trying to access codeigniter libraries for your magento app, then answer is no.

But, if these magento and codeigniter works independently on their own, then its fine.

Comment: Now I got a clear idea about it. Just another small clarification, When I login in Magento's session using that is it possible to authenticate in CodeIgniter's session ? I think it works independently but Just a last try thats why.

Comment: create authenticating function using PHP native session variables. Once you login in magento, set a session variable, so for CI you can check that particular session item to authenticate

Comment: I think it could be a good debugger, I know it's an old question but maybe it's worth trying